# fileEncoding="UTF8" in write.csv does not work

Tags: r

```
df <- dir(getwd(), full.names = T) %>% map_df(~ read_excel(.x, col_names = TRUE))

write.csv(df, file = "mynewfile.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, fileEncoding = "UTF8", quote = FALSE)
```

Unfortunately it is not encoded in UTF8, `ö, 360°` and such still have invalid characters
It works when I save it as write.xlsx but it doesn't work unfortunately when there are bigger amount of rows (like when I had 50k there were memory problem)

Thats how it look - it is a sample (after I've saved it as csv, opened and did text to columns to let it be in diff columns)

[image]

Any suggestions?

Lets say thats how my sample file looks like

df<-data.frame(A = c("ö","ö","ö"), B=c("360°", "360°", "360°"), C= c(123,123,123))
[image]

Comment: have you tried changing the encoding in the data frame? `df[] <- lapply(df, \`Encoding<-\`, 'UTF-8')`

Comment: Hey @rawr. Thanks, it works but partly - as long as vectors are texts, but in my final file I have vectors which are numbers (tel number for instance) as well. Any suggestion?

Comment: just check for strings `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if (is.character(x)) \`Encoding<-\`(x, 'UTF-8') else x)`

Comment: @rawr this is very helpful please add as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try with encoding="UTF-8":

```
write.csv(df, file = "mynewfile.csv", col.names = T, row.names = F, encoding="UTF-8", quote = FALSE)
```

edit: your code is working with my RStudio: Have you set the correct options in your global options: see below. .. Default text encoding...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, 
"UTF8" was my second try. It does'nt work both with UTF8 or UTF-8, thats why I created this thread

Comment: Please sent a minimal reproducible example from your dataframe.

Comment: Hi,
I've added it

Comment: df<-data.frame(A = c("ö","ö","ö"), B=c("360°", "360°", "360°"), C= c(123,123,123))